# Next js basePath and assetPrefix is working when both are same. But when I use a different path for asset prefix it is showing 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
basePath: '/udlejning-sommerhus',
  assetPrefix: '/udlejning-sommerhus/',
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: `/udlejning-sommerhus/_next/:path*`,
        destination: '/_next/:path*'
      }
    ]
  }
```

The above code works fine. But when i make changes like mentioned below

```
basePath: '/udlejning-sommerhus',
  assetPrefix: '/asset-path/',
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: `/asset-path/_next/:path*`,
        destination: '/_next/:path*'
      }
    ]
  }
```

It is showing error.

Note: These are in next.config.js